# Books about human evolution

Tags: human-evolution

I want to read some books about human evolution and about other extincted types of humans.

The book "Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind" writes about history of agricultural and scientific revolution too, which is the part that is not interesting to me as it sounds more like history. However, I want a book about humans living millions years ago up to and before agriculture. I want to know how modern human evolved and what there were besides homo sapiens.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Humans-Evolved-Seventh-Robert-Boyd/dp/0393614867

Comment: It sounds like you are more interested in archaeology and even history than in evolution. This sounds particularly clear as you talk about the scientific revolution. Maybe [History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/) would be a good place to ask this question. Note that evolution, in biology, is usually defined as a change in allele frequency over time (a definition that you may or may not understand) and it does not seem to be what you are interested in. I'm voting to close.

Comment: @Remi.b By mentioning the scientific revolution in "Sapiens: .... " I meant that I am not interested in this part.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about history and archeology and not biology

Answer (score 2):

The Journey of Man is a great book that really dives into the archaeology but also the genetic history of evolution.

Comment: I haven't read this, but I see it's published in 2003. If so, it's completely obsolete, missing enormous technical advances since then, completely unaware of the entire Neandertal interbreeding story, preceding the discovery of at least one branch of Homo (denisovans at the least). Would not recommend.

Comment: It is good to know that a field could change that much dramatically within 15 years. In Physics it is not so much like that! (of course that depends on the sub field)

Answer (score 0):

I came across 'The Last Ape Standing' by Chip Walter that sounds like it might be something you would be interested in.